# Como faço pra importar imagem em Python com a GUI Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tem como colocar imagem no widget da biblioteca tkinter?

Comment: Você tem algum código onde você quer usar a imagem pra mostrar?

Comment: na realidade é a base to TKinter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O 'hello world' de imagem no tkinter é algo parecido com o seguinte código:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

imagem = tk.PhotoImage(file="stack-overflow.png")
w = tk.Label(root, image=imagem)
w.imagem = imagem
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Resultado:

[image: resultado da execução do programa, mostrando imagem]

*P.S. Um caminho completo para a imagem no Windows, seria mais ou menos assim:*

```
imagem = tk.PhotoImage(file="c:/Users/Public/Pictures/stack-overflow.png")
```

Comment: Mas eu posso inserir uma foto da galeria do pc?

Comment: @BiancaSan Sim, só colocar o endereço completo dela.

Comment: muito obrigada:-)

Comment: @BiancaSan incluí no final da resposta um exemplo de caminho completo para um arquivo no computador (precisa agora mudar para o seu caso)

Comment: como eu faria para ajustar o tamanho da imagem ?